# ¿Tiene sentido la frase "decirle a tus hermanos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, plurales, objetos-indirectos

Leo un libro de historias bíblicas para niños, y en la historia de José encuentro algo que para mí es raro:

> Luego, para empeorar las cosas, José tuvo unos sueños especiales:
>
> —¡Yo soñé que era el más grande!  ¡Yo era rey! —les dijo a sus hermanos—. Y todos ustedes se arrodillaban ante mí.
>
> Ahora bien, seguramente sabes, aunque José no lo supiera, **que decirle a tus hermanos** cosas como estas no es muy buena idea.

Para mí, debe ser "decirles a tus hermanos", porque "tus hermanos" es plural.  En forma equivalente pero más simple, sería:

> Seguramente sabes que **decirles** a tus hermanos cosas como estas no es muy buena idea.

Pensaba que era simplemente un error de traducción, pero pregunté a una hispanohablante nativa, y ella me dijo que "decirle" está bien, pero yo no entendí su explicación.

¿Está bien usar "decirle" en este contexto?  Si está bien, ¿a que se refiere "le"?

Comment: @rsanchez ¡Gracias por darme el enlace a tu explicación muy buena!